# How alfresco preview docx files

Tags: alfresco, digital-signature, pdf.js

I am developer of Alfresco. I would like to preview signed docx documents but Alfresco shows the document and hides the digital signature. How Alfresco preview docx files ?

After searching the internet I notice several ways:

-pdfjs convert docx to pdf and shows it in the browser

-an href from google docs

what exactly doing the Alfresco ?

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: Alfresco 5.0 community

Comment: do you know how to use the "node browser" ?

Comment: I would suggest to use the node browser to download the pdf that Alfresco automatically generates. So you can verify if the problem is already in the pdf and not in the preview

Comment: @mrantoni you are using which browser? The browser doesn't gives any error on the preview? 
If the digital signature is made with AcroFields, maybe you have problems on the preview.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I don't know how to use the node browser but I will try.

Comment: @PRVS I am using chrome and mozilla. The preview is working fine but   it hides the signature. I signed pdf, docx documents with cosign. At the beginning  Alfresco does not preview any digital signature on pdf or docx. After searching I noticed that I should comment these 2 lines in pdf.worker.js

 /*if (this.data.fieldType === 'Sig') {
        warn('unimplemented annotation type: Widget signature');
        return false;
      }*/

Comment: But in the pdf the signature appear? Doesn't appear only in the docx? @mrantoni

Comment: @PRVS Now the alfresco preview successfully pdf files with digital signatures. But in docx files hides it.

Comment: @mrantoni but if you put "View on Browser" the signature appears in mozilla and chrome without problems?

In docx what error you obtain?

Comment: @PRVS The view in browser option download the docx file at both mozilla and chrome. And then if i open it the signature is fine. For pdf files chrome shows it perfectly because it uses the adobe plugin but firefox cant shows it because it uses the pdf js . The alfresco uses the same technology (pdf.js) and in order to work you should modify the pdf.worker.js  as i referred above.

Comment: Im testing a similar thing in alfresco but not for docx, you don't know if the docx gives an sacrifíc error? Im trying to help you

Comment: @PRVS The log doesn't give any error

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I found the pdf content which alfresco creates, through node browser, and it is not contain any signature. Therefore the problem is on the conversion. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Is it necessary that the document is a docx and not a pdf ?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to preview both document type pdf and docx